# Paper-Shadow in Core-Pages - Div tag hides polymer paper-shadow

Tags: css, polymer

In the following example the div before the first paper-shadow hides the border of the paper-shadow. The second paper-shadow without div is visible. I want to use the div for layout purpose (center).

What could be the reason? What is the problem here?

The reason for the div is, that I want to center the paper-shadow with layout attributes like 'layout horizontal center'. Using this attributes in the core-pages tag doesn't work.

I don't want write some extra css layout rules for this simple goal.

Here is the code in ele.io

https://ele.io/eidmanna/green-slaw

In ele.io for some reasons the border of both paper-shadow elements are not visible??

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
  <style>
    .card {
      width: 880px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body fullbleed layout vertical>
  <template is="auto-binding" id="templ">
    <core-header-panel flex>

      <core-toolbar class="medium-tall">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <paper-tabs class="bottom fit" selected="{{selectedPage}}">
          <paper-tab>Page1</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>Page2</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
      </core-toolbar>

      <core-pages selected="{{selectedPage}}">
        <!-- this div hides the paper-paper-shadow -->
        <div>
          <paper-shadow z="1" class="card" layout vertical center-center>
            Page 1
          </paper-shadow>
        </div>
        <!-- this paper-shadow is visible -->
        <paper-shadow z="1" class="card" layout vertical center-center>
          Page 2
        </paper-shadow>
      </core-pages>
    </core-header-panel>
    <script>
      var templ = document.querySelector('#templ');
      templ.selectedPage = 0;
    </script>
  </template>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not using :nth-child selector so you can save that extra div, e.g.:

    core-pages > paper-shadow:nth-child(1) {
     /** do you centering here */
    }

However I can't seem to get your example working. I don't see any shadows at all.

Comment: I want to center the paper-shadow with layout attributes like 'layout horizontal center'. layout attributes in the core-pages are ignored. I will edit the question, to understand my real goal.